# optimization of the multiplication of two variables

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization

I have just started learning optimization because I need it in one my projects but I'm totally naive in this field. I was wondering if there is any method to solve a minimization problem of the form:

$$\min_{X,Y}{\left\lVert Z-AXY \right\rVert}_2 ^2 +\alpha \left\lVert X \right\rVert_1 +\beta \alpha \left\lVert Y \right\rVert_1 $$

$Z$ and $A$ are given and they are matrices that I have considered the vectorized format for this optimization problem. I know that if I want to use ADMM I need to change the problem into a summation maybe take logarithm but I'm not sure if that would make any sense?

From somewhere I got the idea of freezing one variable at a time and solve for the other one but I'm not sure if that would work here. Please let me know if it solvable and please mention the methods considering the convexity and non-convexity of the objective function (I want to know both).

Thanks

Comment: Generally, it is very hard to solve the optimizaiton problem of $L_1$ and $L_2$ matrix norm. I do not know your problem, can you replace them by elementwise $L_1$ norm and Frobenius norm? This would makes your problem much easier to solve.

Comment: My main goal is to recover a 2D signal (image), so all of the notations are 2D functions that I have considered as matrices and vectorized them to put them inside the vector norms. X is a multiplicative noise that we are not aware of and we just know it is band limited (Lasso regularizer) and Y is the image that I would like to recover. The rest are given.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for your reply.  is real-valued and  could be even complex

Comment: So, why the tag on discrete optimization? Where is the discreteness?

Comment: Ok, according to your answer, the notation $\|\|_2^2$ is Frobenius norm and $\|\|_1$ is elementwise $L_1$ norm. So it is very suitable to use coordinate descent method. Freezeing one variable then optimize another would definitely work since the function value would decrease after each iteration. And at each iteration you just need to solve a Lasso problem which is well studied.

Answer (score 2):

Let's define two additional variables: $C=X$ and $D=Y$

then we reformulate the original problem as follows

$$\min_{X,Y,C,D} \|Z-AXY\|_2^2 + \alpha\|C\|_1 + \alpha\beta\|D\|_1, \qquad \text{s.t.} C-X=0, \, D-Y=0$$

The augmented Lagrangian multiplier function is

$$\min_{X,Y,C,D} \|Z-AXY\|_2^2 + \alpha\|C\|_1 + \alpha\beta\|D\|_1 + \langle\ \mu_1,C-X\rangle + \frac{\rho_1}{2}\|C-X\|^2_2 + \langle\ \mu_2,D-Y\rangle + \frac{\rho_2}{2}\|D-Y\|^2_2$$

where $\mu_1, \mu_2$ are Lagrang2 multipliers and $\rho_1, \rho_2$ are penalty parameters.

We can now define the ADMM iterations as follows

$$\begin{align*}
X^+ &= arg\min_{X} \|Z-AXY\|_2^2 + \langle\ \mu_1,C-X\rangle + \frac{\rho_1}{2}\|C-X\|^2_2 & \qquad (1)\\
Y^+ &= arg\min_{Y} \|Z-AXY\|_2^2 + \langle\ \mu_2,D-Y\rangle + \frac{\rho_2}{2}\|D-Y\|^2_2 & \qquad (2)\\
C^+ &= arg\min_{C} \alpha\|C\|_1 + \frac{\rho_1}{2}\|C-(X-\frac{\mu_1}{\rho_1})\|^2_2 & \qquad (3)\\
D^+ &= arg\min_{D} \alpha\beta\|D\|_1 + \frac{\rho_2}{2}\|D-(Y-\frac{\mu_2}{\rho_2})\|^2_2 & \qquad (4)\\
\mu_1^+ &= \mu_1 + \rho_1(C-X) & \qquad (5)\\
\mu_2^+ &= \mu_2 + \rho_2(D-Y) & \qquad (6)
\end{align*}$$

For $X$ and $Y$ variables, we take the derivative of (1) and (2) w.r.t X, Y respectively and then we solve these expressions to get the update formulas.

For $C$ and $D$ variables, we use the proximal operator of the $L_1-$norm to obtain a closed-form solution for (3) and (4), which is given by:

$$C^+=sign(Y-\frac{\mu_2}{\rho_2})\odot \max(\frac{\alpha}{\rho_1}(Y-\frac{\mu_2}{\rho_2}), 0), \qquad \text{(1-dimentional shrinkage operator)}$$

The same thing for the $D$ variable.